# Unable to execute dll remotely

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am quite new to C# application development.

I have made a C# console application which I execute like this

```
dotenet.exe <dll_name>
```

This works fine when executed on the system. But I need to call this remotely. I am doing that through Powershell Invoke Command. But I am getting this error.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID
>   {D66FBAAE-4150-402F-8581-75D1652D696A} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

Please note that I have tried many possible solutions on the net:

- Tried changing target for C# app to x86, this doesn't work as the references to the app are x64

Details about the environments:

- Remote is x64
- Client is x64

EDIT

Please find the source code of the dll. This is used for file conversion to a format.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using SolidWorks.Interop.swconst;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class SolidWorkFileConverter
{
    private SldWorks swApplication;
    public SolidWorkFileConverter(SldWorks swApp)
    {
        swApplication = swApp;
    }

    public void ToPdf(string searchPath, string logFileName)
    {
        var logFileDestionation = System.IO.Path.Combine(searchPath, logFileName);
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var partFiles = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath, "*.sldprt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                              .Where(file => !file.Contains("~$"));
        foreach (var drawingFile in partFiles)
        {
            ToStep(drawingFile);
        }
        WriteToLog(logFileDestionation, currentDate);
    }

    public void ToStep(string partFile)
    {
        string destinationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(partFile);
        destinationDirectory = destinationDirectory + "\\output\\";
        string destinationFile = Path.GetFileName(partFile);

        string destinationFileName = ComposeDestinationFileName(Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, destinationFile));
        CreateDestinationDirectory(destinationFileName);


        int state = 0;
        bool status;
        int warningState = 0;
        ModelDoc2 swDoc = (ModelDoc2)(swApplication.OpenDoc6(partFile, 3, 0, "", ref state, ref warningState));
        int warnings = 0;
        int errors = 0;
        PartDoc swPart = (PartDoc)swApplication.OpenDoc6(partFile, (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, (int)swOpenDocOptions_e.swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", ref errors, ref warnings);
        ModelDoc2 swModel = (ModelDoc2)swPart;
        ModelDocExtension swModelDocExt = (ModelDocExtension)swModel.Extension;


        status = swModelDocExt.SaveAs(destinationFileName, 0, (int)swSaveAsOptions_e.swSaveAsOptions_Silent, null, ref errors, ref warnings);

        swDoc = null;
        swApplication.CloseAllDocuments(true);
    }

    private string ComposeDestinationFileName(string sourceFileName)
    {
        return sourceFileName.Replace("PARTS", "STEP").Replace("SLDPRT", "STEP");
    }

    private void CreateDestinationDirectory(string destinationFileName)
    {
        string directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationFileName);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
    }

    private void WriteToLog(string logFileDestination, DateTime currentDate)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logFileDestination, currentDate.ToShortDateString());
    }
}


static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string username = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] == "-user")
            {
                username = args[i + 1];
            }
        }
        string searchPath = "some path"
        string logFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(searchPath, "UpdatedPDFs.txt");

        //SldWorks swApp = new SldWorks();
        SldWorks swApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application")) as SldWorks;

        SolidWorkFileConverter converter = new SolidWorkFileConverter(swApp);
        converter.ToPdf(searchPath, logFileName);
    }
}
```

Edit 2

The powershell command used for remote invocation

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -ScriptBlock { & dotnet.exe convert.dll } -credential  mydomain\administrator
```

Comment: You should probably post the powershell code. There's mention of `COM` in your error message. Does your powershell script use com or does you `dotenet.exe` application use com? Also can you do something trivial remotely? like run some trivial exe?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid How do I check if my application is using COM? Secondly, I am able to execute a bat file remotely. Tried creating a folder with it and it works

Comment: Do you have the application source code? COM was the standard  "unmanaged" application interface that was around before .net. To use it from .net (i.e. when applications only provide a COM API, not a .Net API), you need to use COM interop. Your error mentions COM interop but if you wrote the code and and you've never heard of it then maybe you aren't using it. This is really difficult to troubleshoot in this kind of forum, buit particularly difficult of you don't provide any sample source code (i.e the powershell or the app)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - added the DLL source code

Comment: Is that the source code for the DLL that you pass into `dotenet.exe` or is that the source code for `dotenet.exe`? Anyway... clearly it is using interop. Although that doesn't solve your issue at all.

Comment: Is the root problem that you want to manually convert these files? Historically this is usually done by running a scheduled task on the computer with all the stuff installed (i.e. _SolidWorks_) that polls a folder and if it find anything in there it converts it and puts it into an output folder. So all you do is put your file in this special folder and five minutes later it will appear in another folder, converted.

Comment: The problem with your current approach probably has something to do with the way Powershell does it's remote execution. It can't execute the COM piece of the puzzle due to security or something.

Comment: (1) - this is the source code of the DLL
(2) - we would want to automate it for the users on request. thats why its not a scheduled task
(3) - thats sad
is there any way I can do this? Probably use the dll on the local machine itself (tried that but couldn't make it work)

Comment: Yes there probably is a way to do it but you're going to have to do a lot of fiddling with security etc. If you could post the powershell that might help. (I might not be able to help but someone else might)

Comment: Of course, if you are doing this to _avoid licencing_ then there is no way me or anyone will help. This page http://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/3d-cad/cad-file-conversion.htm appears to indicate that this is something you have to buy

Comment: I am not trying to avoid licensing. I am just creating standalone applications using the APIs that SolidWorks provide:
http://help.solidworks.com/2015/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/gettingstarted/solidworks_api_standalone_and_add-in_applications_overview.htm

Comment: Basically if you installed everything locally (including solidworks) and ran it locally it'd probably work just fine.

Comment: regarding using apis without solidworks, this helps - https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/59190

@Nick.McDermaid - can you help with the remote command invocation error

PS: added the powershell command for remote innvocation